# Is there an easy way to call a method in a frame, when the form that owns it gets activated / deactivated?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

This is about Delphi and the VCL.

I have got several frames that can be used in multiple forms, usually created and added to the form in code. It's possible that a form contains several of these frames. I need to execute some code in these frames when the form that contains it gets deactivated and reverse this when it gets activated.

```
TMyFrame.FormActivated;
TMyFrame.FormDeactivated
```

One solution is to have a FormActivate / FormDeactivate event handler in those forms that call a method of the frames.

```
procedure TMyForm.OnActivate(_Sender: TObject);
begin
  FFrame1.FormActivated;
  FFrame2.FormActivated;
end;
```

This is how I implemented it for now, but that has several disadvantages:

- I have to implement this in every form containing an instance of these frames
- The form has to know that some frames need this call (tight coupling)
- The frames needs to publish two methods to be called in these events. I'd rather not expose these methods.

Another option would be to set a FormActivate / FormDeactivate event from within the constructor of the frame. But this would mean that no other code could be executed in these events and it won't work if there are several of these frames on the same form.

Is there any other option that works for any form containing several of these frames?

I need this for Delphi 2007 if this is important.

Comment: Why not use your own custom message? The form can use it's Components list and send the message to any frames that are on it, and the frames that need to react to it provide a handler for that message. Then it's a simple method on the form (`SendActivationNotification(Activated: Boolean;`, maybe?) that loops and sends the custom message using wParam to pass the boolean indication of whether it's being activated or deactivated.

Comment: You could piggyback the FormActivate/FormDeactivate events in the constructor and pass the event on if set by another component.

Comment: You can write an OnActiveFormChange event handler for the Screen, that keeps track of the active form (to have a reference to the previously active form) and loops all controls in the active and previously active form to find frames and then proceed as in Ken's comment which takes care of the remaining bullets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Assuming VCL) The frame should somehow intercept the parent form's activate/deactivate events. There are many possible ways to do this (setting parent form's `OnActivate`/`OnDeactivate` events, subclassing with [`SetWindowLong`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)`(GWL_WNDPROC)` or [`WindowProc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.WindowProc)) but you'd have to enforce that if multiple frame instances do this to the same form instance the order of removing the hook must be the reverse of inserting the hook. Also, you'd have the problem of correctly handling the cases when window handles get recreated.

An easier approach could be to use something like this as an ancestor of all your forms in the project:

```
TMyForm = class(TForm)
  procedure Activate; override;
  procedure Deactivate; override;
end;

procedure TMyForm.Activate;
begin
  inherited Activate;
  NotifyControls(CM_ACTIVATE);
end;

procedure TMyForm.Deactivate;
begin
  inherited Deactivate;
  NotifyControls(CM_DEACTIVATE);
end;
```

and something like this as an ancestor of all your frames in the project:

```
TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
  procedure CMActivate(var Msg: TCMActivate); message CM_ACTIVATE;
  procedure CMDeactivate(var Msg: TCMDeactivate); message CM_DEACTIVATE;
end;

procedure TMyFrame.CMActivate(var Msg: TCMActivate);
begin
  // parent form activated
end;

procedure TMyFrame.CMDeactivate(var Msg: TCMDeactivate);
begin
  // parent form deactivated
end;
```

This way the coupling is quite loose and it still allows you to override the default `TMyFrame` behaviour by overriding the `CM_ACTIVATE` or `CM_DEACTIVATE` message handler in descendants which need special handling.

Caveats:

1. This has not been tested - it's just a quick suggestion, as a starting point. You might also declare and use your own custom messages instead of `CM_ACTIVATE`/`CM_DEACTIVATE`, to avoid any interference with the rest of the VCL.
2. `NotifyControls` notifies *all* controls - not only frames - but normal controls ignore/don't handle `CM_ACTIVATE`/`CM_DEACTIVATE` messages by default so it shouldn't be a problem. You could also implement your own `NotifyFrames` method.

Comment: In the case of subclassing, if you need multiple subclasses on the same window at the same time, you can use `SetWindowSubclass()` instead of `SetWindowLong()` or `WindowsProc`.  The OS does all of the bookkeeping for you, and the order in which they are installed and removed is not important.

Comment: Turns out that this is the easiest solution since in my current use case all the frames and forms descend from a common ancestor anyway (which I had totally forgotten)

Comment: +1, but note that `NotifyControls` only broadcasts to the immediate child controls. if a frame is not an imidiate child control of the form it wont get the messages.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if this is feasible here, but I had a similar problem some years ago and solved it with some sort of form/frame inheritance. There is a base frame class declaring these methods virtual and a form class that catches the events and iterates over all child frames calling the appropriate frame method. The derived frames override those methods as needed. This reduces coupling to the base classes.

In a later refactoring this was changed to interfaces implemented by the frames, eliminating the coupling between the form and frame classes completely.

Comment: I'm interested in more detail about the interfaced approach: How does the form call the methods? Does it call Supports(component, ISomeInterface, InterfaceVar) for all its components?

Comment: That is the straight forward approach. A more optimized solution may cache the relevant interfaces in a list which is synchronized in an overridden Notification method. Not sure if the performance gain is worth the effort.